# Laravel file upload incorrect name in input field

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

While updating the record, I have created an option to replace the image using file upload, but when doing so in $request->file('headerbanner'), it is getting saved in DB as /tmp/phpCccApH

Controller Code :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{ 

    $clientnewstore = Clientusers::find($id); 
    if($request->hasFile('headerbanner')) {

        $headerbanner = $request->file('headerbanner');
        $mod_headerbanner= date('Y-m-d').'-'.'MQ'.rand(1, 999).'-'.$headerbanner->getClientOriginalName(); 
        $headerbanner->storeAs(public_path().'banners',$mod_headerbanner);
        $request['headerbanner'] = $mod_headerbanner;  

    }


    if($request->hasFile('footerbanner')) {            
        $footerbanner = $request->file('footerbanner');
        $mod_footerbanner= date('Y-m-d').'-'.'MQ'.rand(1, 999).'-'.$footerbanner->getClientOriginalName();
        $footerbanner->storeAs('banners',$mod_footerbanner);
        $request['footerbanner'] = $mod_footerbanner;
    }




    Clientusers::find($id)->update($request->all());

   $request->session()->flash('message','Record Successfully Updated');
    return redirect('/user_accounts');
}
```

HTML file

```
        <form action="/user_accounts" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                   {{ csrf_field() }}
            <h4> Header / Footer Settings</h4>
            <div class="form-group row py-2">
                <div class="col-sm-6 pr-4">
                    <label for="headerbanner">Header Banner</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control"  id="headerbanner"  name="headerbanner"    />
                </div> 

                <div class="col-sm-6">  
                    <label for="footerbanner">Footer Banner</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control"  id="footerbanner" class="form-control"   name="footerbanner" >
                </div>    
            </div>   
      <div class="float-right text-right">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success float-right">
             <i class="fas fa-check px-2"></i> Save
         </button>
      </div>
```

Comment: That's the temporary location of the file before the submit. You need to move the file into a specified location and then provide the new path of the file to the table's column.

Comment: @1ns4n3 can you please explain on how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Run command "php artisan storage:link"

Try something like below.

```
if ($request->hasFile('footerbanner')) {
        $file = $request->footerbanner;
        $imageurl = Storage::disk('local')->put($current_timestamp . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName(), file_get_contents($file), 'public');
        ; // To make file unique in the same folder.
    }
```

After this, you can store that imageurl to the model.

Comment: I've tried your code. I'm getting the following error "Unable to create the "upload" directory. ...tried by adding public path didn't help...any idea ?

Comment: it was already linked "...it shows The "public/storage" directory already exists."

Comment: I have updated my code snippet a little bit. Check if that works for you.

Comment: Now the code works but file name is saved as "/tmp/phpJMjmkx"

Comment: Can you update the code snippet you are using in the question again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177194/discussion-between-1ns4n3-and-vinod-kumar).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('footerbanner')) {

$path = $request->file('footerbanner')->storeAs('public/upload',$request->footerbanner->getClientOriginalName().'.'.$extension);
}
```

Note: make sure you have upload folder in storage/app/public/

Comment: This code too works but filename in db is stored as "/tmp/phpJMjmkx"

Comment: what is the name of your file you are uploading?

Comment: file name is sample222.png

Comment: return $request->footerbanner->getClientOriginalName(); and let me know output what you get?you should get output sample222.png

Answer (score 0):

I have used this following function to save my profile images - you could try this. I have just edited the image name as according to yours.

```
public function save_profile_image(Request $request)
{
    $image = $request->file('profile_image');
    $destinationPath = public_path('/profile_images');

    $image_name = date('Y-m-d').'-'.'MQ'.rand(1, 999).'-'.$request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalName()
    $image->move($destinationPath, $image_name);

    $image_path = $destinationPath.'/'.$request->file('profile_image')->getClientOriginalName();
    if (!File::exists($image_path)) {
        return response()->json(['msg'=>'File not found','success'=>false,'code'=>401]);
    }

    $image_url = url('/public/profile_images/'.$image_name);

    return $image_url;
}
```